# How can I add a thousands separator in those lines of code?

Tags: javascript, html, math, separator

I have been googling for this, but I found the solutions difficult, so I came here to ask how can I do it.
I'm doing an [incremental game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_game) and I want to start with the basics: mining gold and buying. Now I'm moving to my next step at developing this game and I really need help

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Gold Miner</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="goldMined">0 Gold Mined</h2>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button onclick="buyGoldPerClick()" id="perClickUpgrade">Get More Money. Cost: 10 Gold</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button onclick="Reset()">Reset Game</button>
    <script src="main.js" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var gameData = {
    gold: 0,
    goldPerClick: 0.01,
    goldPerClickCost: 10,
    tickReduction: 1000,
    tickReductionCost: 100
}

function mineGold() {
    gameData.gold += gameData.goldPerClick
    document.getElementById("goldMined").innerHTML = gameData.gold.toFixed(0).toLocaleString('en') + " Gold Mined"
    document.getElementById("perClickUpgrade").innerHTML = "Buy Pickaxe. Cost: " + gameData.goldPerClickCost.toFixed(0).toLocaleString('en') + " Gold"
}

function buyGoldPerClick() {
    if (gameData.gold >= gameData.goldPerClickCost) {
        gameData.gold -= gameData.goldPerClickCost
        gameData.goldPerClick *= 2
        gameData.goldPerClickCost *= 3
        document.getElementById("goldMined").innerHTML = gameData.gold.toLocaleString('en') + " Gold Mined"
        document.getElementById("perClickUpgrade").innerHTML = "Buy Pickaxe. Cost: " + gameData.goldPerClickCost.toLocaleString('en') + " Gold"
    }
}

function Reset() {
    gameData.gold = 0
    gameData.goldPerClick = 0.01
    gameData.goldPerClickCost = 10
}

var mainGameLoop = window.setInterval(function () {
    mineGold()
}, 10)

var saveGameLoop = window.setInterval(function () {
    localStorage.setItem("goldMinerSave", JSON.stringify(gameData))
}, 1)

var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goldMinerSave"))
if (savegame !== null) {
    gameData = savegame
}
```

Any help supports a lot for me, as I am a JavaScript and HTML programming beginner! Thanks for reading my post!

Comment: What is your question? You don't ask one

Comment: How can I add thousands separator in those numbers?

Comment: In what numbers? Please try to be specific and narrow down the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to get the thousand separator in the gold amount and price amount.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NumberFormat() function from the [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) available in Javascript. (click on the link for documentation).

1. The first parameter to the Intl.NumberFormat() function is the locale, if you want it to be generic, just pass in 'en-US'. But if you can also pass in **navigator.language** if you want to just take the language from the browser.
2. The second parameter to this function is an options object. Now, within this options object, I have passed in the maximumSignificantDigits and set it to 3. You can change that as per your requirements. You also have other options you can pass in, just check out the link I provided above.
3. Finally, you will be calling the format() function and passing in your gold as the parameter, and this will overall return you the formatted value with 3 maximum significant digits.

```js
const gold = 1000000;

const formattedGold = Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(gold);

//Printing output to console
console.log(formattedGold);
```